# How come when floating a div inside a fieldset to the left, it actually floats right?

Tags: css, html, css-float, fieldset

here is the html:

```
<fieldset>
   <div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

here is the css:

```
fieldset
{
  float:  left;
  width:  200px;
}
   fieldset > div
   {
      float:  left;
      width:  100px;
   }
```

and for some reason the div appears to be floating right, why is that?

Comment: Looks fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/EMjqK/

Comment: Yep, and looks to be left-floated [here, too](http://jsfiddle.net/Dzmm8/). I'd suggest that you have conflicting styles elsewhere in your stylesheet. Try using Firebug (Firefox), or Web Inspector (Chrome/Safari), to see what styles are being applied to the elements.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine for me too. Maybe you did not post your whole code which causes problems.

Comment: Post the URL, so we can take a look into the problem.  
If it's not working for you, there's probably another CSS rule that is overriding yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works fine with me. It floats to the left, instead to the right.
Here's something that I tried,
Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="index1.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
<div> </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

and index1.css

```
fieldset
{
  float:  left;
  width:  200px;
}
fieldset > div
{
     float:  left;
     width:  100px;
  }
```

and the fieldset is on the left.

Have a look here : [Floating div to left inside the fieldset](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3882728.htm)